# Headache when working out

Tags: gym

Recently, I've started getting headaches mainly after leg-pressing on the machine.
They used to be pretty short and only last a few minutes, but they got worse and now they last for the full work-out + a few hours after I leave the gym.
Has anyone experienced this before? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Are you hydrated and fed when you work out?

Comment: I think so. I try to eat and drink about 2 hours before going to the gym and during the workout I drink around 1.5l of water

Comment: @freefrag sometimes it happens to me after spending the whole day coding a tough and stressful task. I get exhausted and when i go workout i get a headache. Maybe you are working lots of hours?

Comment: You might want to have your blood pressure measured.

Comment: @shadesco I doubt it's that, I'm a student and I don't usually overwork myself.

Comment: @MischaArefiev thanks for the tip, I'll try to get my hands on a BP monitor

Comment: are you getting enough oxygen? Are you allowing yourself to breathe?

Comment: What type of leg-press machine are you using? I've seen ones where you more or less lie down while pressing, which I'd try to avoid. Does it feel okay when you do regular squats?

Comment: I get headaches since I started trying to do chin-ups that I never got over the past few months when I was doing just running and push-ups. @MischaArefiev: Is it a sign of high or low blood pressure? I remember years ago I had low blood pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like squats, leg press is one of those exercises where you may see stars if your blood circulation is bad, you are dehydrated, or you are not breathing correctly. If it is none of that, it could just be benign [exertion headaches](http://www.headaches.org/education/Headache_Topic_Sheets/Exertional_Headaches).

Whatever it is, I would see a doctor immediately. Not to scare you, but if you have an underlying condition then doing leg presses is just asking for an aneurysm. Better to get an MRI then be sorry.

Comment: I think you mean "better to get an MRI *than* be sorry". The system won't let me edit it...

Comment: Your link to exertion headaches has gone bad. Could you please re-link?

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what was said already, try drinking more water. not freezing cold ice water, but cool or room temperature. dehydration is what starts the headaches, and hydrating should make it feel better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking protein shakes before you start training?  You might be allergic to whey (milk) which causes headaches for me.

Otherwise its likely that you are simply dehydrated.